# Why action method parameter is null after postback call occurred?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net mvc 5 project.

I have problem to pass string value to action method after selection made by user  from `ul li` html element.

Here is HTML code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <ul class="top-links list-inline" >
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle no-text-underline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" />NORSK</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-langs dropdown-menu" name="culture">
                <li><a value="no" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="~/assets/images/flags/no.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang"/>NORSK</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a value="us" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/us.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> ENGLISH</a></li>
                <li><a value="de" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/de.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> GERMAN</a></li>
                <li><a value="ru" tabindex="-1"><img class="flag-lang" src="/assets/images/flags/ru.png" width="16" height="11" alt="lang" /> RUSSIAN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
}
```

jQuery code fired after selection implemented:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var plugin_path = '/assets/plugins/';
    (function ($) {
        $('ul[name = "culture"]').click(function () {
            $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

And here is action method in server side:

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture) 
{ 
    culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
    // Save culture in a cookie
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
    if (cookie != null)
        cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
    else
    {

        cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
        cookie.Value = culture;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The action method above fired after selection of the user was made.

But the problem that `culture` parameter is always null!

So my question is why `culture` parameter is always null? I am expecting the culture parameter to be according to the value selected in  `li HTML` element.

Comment: `<ul name="culture">` inside `<form>` isn't sent to the server. Only form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>` etc) will be considered as part of the form data.

Comment: @haim770 , any idea how can I adopt my html code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, a UL will never post  back a value - because there is no selection capability.  What you can do is have a hidden `<select>` element, with all of the values, and on click of an item in the list, use JavaScript to change the select, and post that value back to the server.  Or store a `<input type="hidden" name="culture" />` associated with the UL; when an LI is clicked, update the hidden field using JavaScript, and post that value back to the server instead.

If you are only sending one value to the server, you could just setup an li CLICK event, and on click post the value using `$.ajax` instead too.

EDIT: you can update a hidden field with something like the following, which finds all A tags within the drop down list (targeted by CSS class, but could be whatever).

```
$(".dropdown-langs").find("li a").on("click", function() {
   var lang = $(this).attr("value");
   $("#hiddenID").val(lang);

   $(this).parents("form").submit();
});
```

Something like that.

Comment: Brian thanks for your post. I decided  to create  hidden input type as you described in the post.I weak in Jquery can you please show example how can I fetch the  value from selected li element?

Here what I tried: $('ul li a').html().val()

Comment: @Michael, your elements are not form controls and do not have `value` attributes - it needs to be `.text()` - `$('a').click(function() { var lang = $(this).text(); // make ajax post });`

Comment: I updated my comment above.  I actually think you want to target the A tag value property right?  My update shows that above.  Replace #hiddenID with the ID of the control (make sure the # remains as that targets the ID directly.